# Delete all tables in one shot in Ms access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-delete

Here is my VBA code, which tries to loop through all the tables which contains `PB` (PB is the first two letters of all of the tables) in their name and delete them. I get the error msg at `DoCmd` line

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub del_all_tables()
   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
   Set db = CurrentDb

   For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
       If Not (tdf.Name Like "PB*") Then
           DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tdf.Name
       End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Edit: I would like to not to delete the tables itself but delete the records inside the tables

Comment: What error message? Edit question. Your code is attempting to delete tables that do not have PB in name, this would include system tables.

Comment: Im newbie here in VBA and Access. and I just realised that if this code would have worked all tables would be deleted but  I dont want to delete table I want to delete the records in side all tables with on shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DELETE action SQL to remove records. Use `CurrentDb.Execute` and don't have to worry about turning Warnings off and on.

`CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM [" & tdf.Name & "]"`.

If you want to delete records only from tables starting with `PB`, remove `Not` from the condition - otherwise you will delete from all other tables (including system tables which is bad).

```
Public Sub del_all_records()
   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
   Set db = CurrentDb

   For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
       If tdf.Name Like "PB*" Then
           db.Execute "DELETE FROM [" & tdf.Name & "]"
       End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please provide a full code?

Answer (score 0):

My original code is to delete the all the tables what did not work. I took the source from here.  https://access-excel.tips/access-vba-loop-through-all-tables/

But if you would like to delete all the records in multiple tables with one shot, you need to create delete queries for each table separately.

Then you can use VBA to  openeach query and run with the following code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function RunMyqueries()
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query1"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query2"


MsgBox "Done!"

End Function
```

In my case I have 2 queries, if you have more just continue added them.

Also, you might want to turn off the Warning everytime before deleting the records with  `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`

Comment: Then you have to turn Warnings back on at end of procedure `DoCmd.SetWarnings True`.

Comment: Yes, thanks for adding it

Answer (score 0):

First the object name in the docmd statement is causing error, because you are not calling a full object name, rather you are trying to use the like operator.

Secondly if you want to delete records and not the table, then you have to use a delete statement.

You can play around with the query design view to have a feel of how the delete statement/query in access is.

Comment: I just answered my self, you can take a look on mine and suggest something better if it comes to mind

Comment: No, the object name reference is just fine.